# CMAKE: get location of windows import lib

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, cmake

Using cmake on windows in visual studio 2012, I need to get the location of the import lib.  I can get the location of my dll target as:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(foo SHARED ${CXX_SRCS})
GET_TARGET_PROPERTY(FOO_NAME foo LOCATION)
```

Now that I have the path to foo.dll, I need the path to the import lib, foo.lib.  Is there a cmake property for this?  If so, what is the minimum cmake required?

Comment: Are you positive you actually need the location?  You can link against the library directly by specifying the target name in `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES()`.  You can install both parts of the library with `install(TARGETS ... RUNTIME ... LIBRARY)`.

Comment: Yes, I need the location.  I don't want to use the install target, I want this as a post-build step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create post-build step that depends on other target's import .lib file, use "generator expression" `TARGET_LINKER_FILE` in [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_custom_command):

`$<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:tgt> = file used to link (.a, .lib, .so)`

You can also look on target property [ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_tgt:ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY), but VS2012 generator appends CONFIGURATION to this directory and you have to set it manually.

Comment: Thank you.  I had been looking at target properties, and not generator expressions.